# Odd varnish behavior after saving a product. Hit idle send timeout

Tags: magento2, varnish

Magento 2.2.6, varnish 5.2.1.  I'm on a product page, hit it twice to get a cache hit.  Then I update the product from the back end and hit refresh on the product.  The page will load fairly quickly (faster than the idle send timeout value) and show a cache hit.  But I know that isn't correct since it has been purged from varnish on the save.  While watching the varnish logs I see that there are actually two requests for the product page.  The first is a cache miss but shows this debug message

```
-   Debug          "Hit idle send timeout, wrote = 32768/794307; retrying"
-   Debug          "Write error, retval = -1, len = 761539, errno = Broken pipe"
```

The second entry in the log shows the cache hit which is what I'm seeing in the browser.

Another odd thing is that the first wrote value in the debug message, 32768, is always the same.  I've tried adding all kinds of varnish start up values for:

http_resp_hdr_len

http_resp_size

http_req_hdr_len

http_req_size

idle_send_timeout

workspace_client

workspace_backend

gzip_buffer

http_max_hdr

Checking param.show shows me that the values I'm setting are taking effect. Bur nothing seems to help.  And I've tried on other product pages as well.  It's the same scenario and the same wrote value.  Where else should I look?

Comment: Can you correlate those errors to exactly your own requests? [This thread](https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2017-September/026165.html) suggests that these may happen if a client is dropping connection (e.g. closed browser).

Comment: I'd like to see the full `varnishlog` output for the failed transaction, as well as the VCL code that is executed.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin It is my request.  This is a staging server and I'm filtering out the specific URL that I am using to test with.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn you can view everything here https://pastebin.com/JMd45Xpv

Comment: @nbucko it looks like the failed request comes from Amasty crawler, not yourself; based on `Cookie: PHPSESSID=amasty-fpc-crawler;`. So it can easily be a failed cron job run, thus check for fatal PHP errors with exceeded memory limits, etc.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Thank you for pointing that out.  That is exactly what was happening.  This is a heavily customized site, we have automatic re-warming of saved product pages that runs from cron.  So if we hit the page before the cron has run the page takes so long to load that the cron runs before the page is rendered in the browser.  The cron gets the cache miss, the page loads immediately after and shows a cache hit.

Waiting two minutes after saving the product ensures the cron has run and the page gets served from varnish as expected.